# Set page that wordpress loads programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently trying to setup a php-function, that sets the page that wordpress loads. I use a hook in my functions.php of my (child-)theme to determine when i want to display the special page.
I am looking at something like `update_option('page_for_posts', 'page123')` but not specifically for the front page.

Background: I need to make a redirect kind of thing, that i cant solve with an htaccess, because i need to redirect based on database-entries. The redirect has to not be notices by the users of the page.

I tried redirects via `update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );` and `update_option( 'page_for_posts', 'Beispiel-Seite' );` but i didnt get the desired results

```
function setupRedirect() {
    // Determine which page/site to redirect to

    // redirect the site
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $pageRedirectNameOrID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

Edit:
I found a few posts about the `add_rewrite_rule()` function but i cant get it to work.
Thats what i got so far.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'url-getting-called',
    'post-url-to-redirect-to',///?slug='.$eiaSite->slug,
    'top'
);
```

I refreshed/re-saved the perma-links but its not working...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `template_include` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) to change the template that's loaded, which could explicitly pull data from that other page; add the following to your theme's `functions.php` or an mu-plugin (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'template_include', static function ( $template ) {
    $switch_to_special = false; // logic to change template

    if ( ! $switch_to_special ) {
        return $template;
    }

    return get_theme_file_path( 'template-special.php' );
} );
```